# cannot show data fetched from databse in the table

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

actually i am trying to get data of 95 people from the database(monogodb) but i cannot display the data in my table i can see that the database and api is working properly when i console log my result variable it show me data properly but the data is not shown on the table.

here is my react code:

```
 import { useState } from "react";
import "./Nagarnigam.css"
import { Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function ForthWinner({ data }) {
    const   FetchData = [];
    const [state, setstate] = useState([]);

    async function GET() {
    
        for(let i=0;i<95;i++){

            let SR_NO = data();

            let result = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/search/${SR_NO}`);

            result = await result.json();

             console.log(result);

            FetchData.push(result);

        }

            setstate(FetchData);
    }

    return (
        <div className="TableDiv1">

            <Table striped bordered hover >
                <tbody>
                    <tr >
                        <td>PARTNER</td>
                        <td>PROPERTY_OWNER_NAME</td>
                        <td>WARD</td>
                        <td>ZONE_PT</td>
                        <td>ASSMENTYEAR</td>
                        <td>TAX_AMT</td>
                        <td>SR_NO</td>

                    </tr>


                    {
                        state.map((item) =>
                            <tr key={item.SR_NO}>
                                <td>{item.PARTNER}</td>
                                <td>{item.PROPERTY_OWNER_NAME}</td>
                                <td>{item.WARD}</td>
                                <td>{item.ZONE_PT}</td>
                                <td>{item.ASSMENTYEAR}</td>
                                <td>{item.TAX_AMT}</td>
                                <td>{item.SR_NO}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                </tbody>

            </Table>

            <div className="buttondiv">
                <Button variant="outline-success" onClick={GET}>Forth Winners</Button>{' '}
                <Button variant="outline-success"  >Save data</Button>{' '}
            </div>

        </div>
    )

}
export default ForthWinner;
```

here is my api i think it is working fine.

```
app.get("/search/:key", async (req, resp) => {
    const key = req.params.key;
    let result = await database.find({ SR_NO: key })
    resp.send(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your API works correctly, the problem is in your React code. I saw how you are fetching the actual data - it's wrong. Try to load your data in this way:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; // in your case -> 
// const arr =  Array.from({ length: 95 }, (_, index) => index + 1);

function ForthWinner({ data }) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState(); // in your case table data
  // you can create sepatate hook for this logic to handle loading status and data
  // I made it simple

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      // Get promises array
      const promises = arr.map(async (postId) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${postId}`
        );
        return await response.json();
      });

      // executed promises to get the actual data
      const _posts = await Promise.all(promises.map(async (p) => await 
p));
      console.log(_posts);
      setPosts(_posts);
    })(); // <- IIFE
  }, []); //fetch only on init (only one time)

  return <div>Table</div>;
}
```

Do **NOT** update your component state like this:

```
FetchData.push(result);
```

It's incorrect and can lead to different side effects.
You can read why it's bad practice [here](https://dev.to/il3ven/common-error-accidentally-mutating-state-in-react-4ndg).

Other resources:

- [How to manage your React component state](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-manage-react-states-like-a-pro-4127cf7df5e0)
- [How to fetch async data in React](https://www.developerway.com/posts/how-to-fetch-data-in-react)

Comment: The data prop is sending a random number for which data is fetched from database i cannot use the array even when I used your solution it shows me empty table without any data can u or any one provide an easier solution